# How to get a list of user sessions (last month entries) for Essbase Administration Services?

Tags: essbase

I need an script or a way to know how many users (and if possible who) that logged using smartview to an aplication database within the last month.

Answer (score 0):

You find that information in the logfile of the application, simply parse it for the code essbase uses to indicate a user login.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57185_01/ESBEM/launch.html